# Java model trying to create tables

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee-6

My java model is causing these warnings in my logs...

```
WARNING: PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, last_login TIMESTAMP, name VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id))": java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'USERS' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
WARNING: PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE GUEST (ID BIGINT NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID))": java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'GUEST' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
WARNING: PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE content (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, body CLOB(2147483647), user_id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (id))": java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'CONTENT' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
WARNING: PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "CREATE TABLE SEQUENCE (SEQ_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, SEQ_COUNT DECIMAL(15), PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_NAME))": java.sql.SQLException: Table/View 'SEQUENCE' already exists in Schema 'APP'.
WARNING: PER01000: Got SQLException executing statement "INSERT INTO SEQUENCE(SEQ_NAME, SEQ_COUNT) values ('SEQ_GEN', 0)": java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL111211163034730' defined on 'SEQUENCE'.
```

I actually have a couple of questions here...

`users` and `content` tables I created already, and used Netbeans to generate my models.

*How come it's trying to create the tables when the models were created from the tables?*

*Secondly, I have no idea where `sequence` is coming from?*

Comment: which framework you are using to do ORM ?

Comment: @JigarJoshi - Just persistence... in Netbeans I right clicked and selected "Create new Model" and it connected to my table and generated the model

Comment: Is there some `persistence.xml` file in your project?

Comment: You're right, there was something there to create tables...